# How to access files stored in /github/workspace?

Tags: github, version-control, workflow, github-actions

I am trying to create a workflow for my repo using an action which auto generates a changelog. Ideally the generated changelog should be present in the root of the master branch. But the build log of the workflow states that the CHANGELOG.md file has been stored in /github/workspace. How to solve this problem or how to access the CHANGELOG.md file?

```
name: Generate Changelog
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Update Changelog
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up changelog
        uses: heinrichreimer/github-changelog-generator-action@v2.1.1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It outputs the file to your current working directory on your runner. It creates a link between the docker dir the `github-changelog-generator-action` is running on.

E.g. `/usr/bin/docker run <... omitted> -v "/home/runner/work/TestGithubActions/TestGithubActions":"/github/workspace"` when the repository name containing the workflow is `TestGithubActions`.

Adding `ls` to your workflow

```
name: Generate Changelog
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Update Changelog
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up changelog
        uses: heinrichreimer/github-changelog-generator-action@v2.1.1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - run: |
          ls
```

outputs this:

```
Run ls
CHANGELOG.md
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I don't understand how the answer above would output that file into the repository?

Comment: This answer just shows, that the file is generated on the runner's file system. If you want to persist it in your git repository, you have to commit and push it.

Comment: Usually, you are better of using something like https://github.com/googleapis/release-please to automate the committing of the Changelog.